# How to get handle of the current workbook's window?

Tags: excel, vsto

How to get handle of the main window of the current workbook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, there is only one window that mimics multi-window behavior; thus, getting Application.Hwnd is enough

Comment: This may no longer be the case in Excel 2013.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question is labeled with VSTO, I suppose the author is looking for means to get a handle of the current window in VSTO code. In C#, try:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the actual HWND? If so, I'd use WinSpy++ with the pointer tool to ID the window. That'll give you the handle, but more importantly, the class ID of the window, so that you can use ENUMWINDOWS to enumerate through all of excel's Child windows to find those of that particular class.

Comment: There are many such windows, because each workbook has it's own main window.